# Increase brightness level without using backlight

Tags: screen-brightness

I'm looking for a way to increase "software" level of brightness in Android without changing the "hardware" level, just like as if I was applying a brightness filter to an image file in Photoshop.

I've tried some apps like Screen Filter, but they seem to only decrease brightness below 0%.

Desired effect shown below, doesn't have to be super high quality.
[image: desired effect]

Comment: I understand that it's not going to look exactly like in the picture, it is only there for demonstration purposes.

Comment: Changing brithnes and other display related parameters can not be influenced by apps. The brightness decreasing apps you have mentioned just us a trick by showing a permanent overlay over everything and that overlay has alpha transparency set to reduce brightness of the background that is shining through. Touches are also going through that overlay. This technique only allows to reduce brightness but not the opposite.

Comment: @Robert Thanks for the explanation, it all makes sense now. I wonder if it's possible to use the same trick but with white semi-transparent overlay, but that's probably a topic for another unrelated question.